# How do I configure the OfficeJS samples to sideload on desktop and use Node/NPM for testing?

Tags: node.js, excel, npm, office-js

OfficeJS suggests using Node and NPM to test add-ins. They have some samples at the following link:
https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-samples/tree/main/Samples/excel-keyboard-shortcuts

Using the Yeoman generator, I can take the files and run "npm start", which automatically sideloads the add-in to the desktop version of Excel. These samples are not configured as such. The samples suggest starting a local server, then uploading the manifest to Excel for Web, then testing it there.

Is there a standard package.json and webpack I could use, like from the Yeoman generator, or do they need to be customized?

Comment: There is literally instructions on that link for NPM --> https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-samples/tree/main/Samples/excel-keyboard-shortcuts#run-the-sample-from-localhost